# Point cloud with individual color

Tags: opengl

I can draw 3D points in one color, let say green.
But I fail to apply individual color to each point.

```
bool applyColor = true;
glPointSize(3);
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
glColor3ub(0,255,0);

for(auto vpMP : vpMPs){
    if(applyColor){
        cv::Vec3b rgb = vpMP->rgb;
        glColor3ub(rgb[2], rgb[1], rgb[0]);
        cout << (int)rgb[0] << ", " << (int)rgb[1] << ", " << (int)rgb[2] << endl;  // Prints out right values
    }
    cv::Mat pos = vpMP->GetWorldPos();
    glVertex3f(pos.at<float>(0),pos.at<float>(1),pos.at<float>(2));
}
glEnd();
```

Any clue?

glVertex3f works fine, points appear where they should be.

With applyColor=false, points show up green.

With applyColor=true, points show up black, when they should be rgb.  BTW, rgb[i] are unsigned char.

Thank you!

Comment: So what do you see in `cout`? What values are there in `vpMP->rgb`?

Comment: cout prints lines like this:  `244, 98, 12`     all correct rgb values from 0 to 255.

Comment: It means that the problem is in the code you didn't show. Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: So, you think this code is right.  I'm using Pangolin to build the window and show this point cloud.  I'll post a MCVE.

Comment: Also you use a 8-year deprecated fixed-function-pipepline. I really recommend you move to modern OpenGL. The problem might go away automagically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't make my old code work, and, as @ybungalobill pointed out, that code used old deprecated fixed-function-pipeline, so I moved to this more modern approach that works.

Showing only partial code:

```
bool color = true;
struct glPunto{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    uchar r;
    uchar g;
    uchar b;
    char padding[17];   // Así la estructura es múltiplo de 32 bytes
};
glPunto glPuntos[N];


int i = 0;
for(auto punto : vpMPs){
    cv::Mat pos = punto->GetWorldPos();
    auto rgb = punto->rgb;

    glPunto &glp = glPuntos[i++];

    glp.x = pos.at<float>(0);
    glp.y = pos.at<float>(1);
    glp.z = pos.at<float>(2);

    if(color){
        glp.r = rgb[2];
        glp.g = rgb[1];
        glp.b = rgb[0];
    } else {
        glp.r = 0;
        glp.g = 0;
        glp.b = 0;
    }
}

glPointSize(color?4:2);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(glPunto), &glPuntos[0].x);
glEnableClientState (GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glColorPointer(3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, sizeof(glPunto), &glPuntos[0].r);

glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, i);

glDisableClientState (GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState (GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

This still doesn't represent the state of the art.  It would be better if it used glVertexAttribPointer.